# After UrlDecode nothing changes

Tags: javascript, c#, uri

In `JavaScript` I encode part of `uri`:

```
var imageName = "test space in name of image.jpg"
var sentWithAjaxVariable = encodeURIComponent(imageName);
//sentWithAjaxVariable in console is "test%20space%20in%20name%20of%20image.jpeg"
```

On server side, in handler I want to decode this variable like this:

```
var imageName = context.Request.Params["sentWithAjaxVariable"];
var decodedImageName = context.Server.UrlDecode(imageName);
//decodedImageName in watch => "test%20space%20in%20name%20of%20image.jpeg"
```

why not decode?

Comment: Check imageName before decoding in case you've managed to encode it twice by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It's the respective .NET method for `decodeURIComponent` in JS.